# 'exportKey' function not recognized in pycrypto-2.6.1(python 2.7.6) ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pycrypto

Hello I'm trying to run this simple code to generate a private key:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(2048)
f = open('mykey.pem','w')
f.write(RSA.exportKey('PEM'))
f.close()
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "erase-this.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.write(RSA.exportKey('PEM'))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exportKey'
```

I checked inside /pycrypto-2.6.1/lib/Crypto/PublicKey, and the function

```
def exportKey(self, format='PEM', passphrase=None, pkcs=1):
```

is present inside RSA.py.

Does someone knows why I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exportKey'???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exportKey()` is a method of the key, not a module function. So you need to do

```
f.write(key.exportKey('PEM'))
```

Here's a short demo (using a smaller key size).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(1024)
print key.exportKey('PEM')

pub_key = key.publickey()
print pub_key.exportKey('PEM')
```

**typical output**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDqYiWx1bwP0aF0TJhRBXzFv+WB
PUKD965CbvoU/xiMj7Eu5crD36k6t44Po696gxVN+rGWUo2VKFVUsi1A3oqhkyFn
F6JJxkt42w4sUVNd91PvBzxIermBnciyhPjJY8pfWWSaGwZxdqSfBDieeCfAk7NK
W8aRzfP178Mz4mCwYQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```